# How to change the cursor from "text" to "default" when using the detail tag

Tags: html, wordpress, inline, inline-code

I used the detail tag in a blog post on Wordpress and I would like the default cursor to appear instead of the text cursor (which displays by default). If you could show a solution using strictly inline CSS, I would appreciate it. (I don't have access to CSS on my Wordpress blog.)

Link to example image: http://esploded.com/f/cursor-snappng/

I tried doing this:

```
<p style="cursor:default">
<details> 
<summary style="outline: none;">Alabama</summary>
Domino’s
Donatos
</details>
</p>
```

but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Try adding it to the details tag rather than the containing <p>

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed. Wordpress keeps deleting the code I write in the "text" editor, which is frustrating and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
<p>
<details style="cursor:default"> 
<summary style="outline: none;">Alabama</summary>
Domino’s
Donatos
</details>
</p>
```

Also, pointer is not default. If you do want the pointer just make the change. The only difference is that the stlye is on the details tag instead. I tested and it worked for me : http://jsfiddle.net/w4L6T/

Answer (score 2):

SOmething like this ? I think you should use `default` vs `pointer`

Ref:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

```
 <p>
   <details style="cursor:default"> 
    <summary style="outline: none;">Alabama</summary>
      Domino’s Donatos
   </details>
```